# "raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None" I'm trying to read and write to a json File

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Good afternoon, I'm trying to read from a json file that has a dictionary structure inside of it then update it to store more entries by overwriting it with the updated dictionary. However I'm getting this error, I have no idea whats causing it I've been trying to fix it for 10 hours, it happens when I try to use json.load and store it a variable
This is the error I'm getting:

```
JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

```
import json

Group = {}
Group["Users"] = {}

def Update_New(struct,File):
    EMAIL = input("Email")
    User = input("User")
    Pass = input("Pass")
    Group = struct.copy()
    Group["Users"].update({{EMAIL: {'Username': User, "Password": Pass}}})
    File.seek(0)
    json.dump(Group,File)


def main():
    with open('Knuckle.json', 'w+') as File:
        data = json.load(File)
        Update_New(data,File)
        print(data)
main()
```

Comment: ``json.load`` takes a file stream in read mode, not in write mode https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html.

Comment: Thanks This helped also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `Knuckle.json` is empty so it cant be parsed as JSON and converted to a python dict.

Comment: Thank's I'm going to try this now I think it was a combination of Sushanth's answer and yours!